# Login function with JwtBearer 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#

After running that part have error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
     tokenDescriptor.Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, $"{user.role.Name}")

                });
```

There is code for all that class

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RestaurantApi.Entities;
using RestaurantApi.Exceptions;
using RestaurantApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace RestaurantApi.Services
{
    public interface IAccountService
    {
        void RegisterUser(RegisterUserDto dto);
        public string GenerateJwt(LoginDto dto);
    }

    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        private readonly RestaurantDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IPasswordHasher<User> _passwordHasher;
        private readonly AuthenticationSettings _authenticationSettings;
        public static class F
        {
            public static string Dump(object obj)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            }
        }
        public AccountService(RestaurantDbContext context, IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, AuthenticationSettings authenticationSettings)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
            _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
            _authenticationSettings = authenticationSettings;
        }
        public void RegisterUser(RegisterUserDto dto)
        {
            var newUser = new User
            {
                Email = dto.Email,
                DateOfBirth = dto.DateOfBirth,
                Nationality = dto.Nationality,
                RoleId = dto.RoleId,
            };
            var hashedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(newUser, dto.Password);

            newUser.PasswordHash = hashedPassword;
            _dbContext.Users.Add(newUser);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public string GenerateJwt(LoginDto dto)
        {
            var user = _dbContext.Users.Include(user=>user.role).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == dto.Email);
            if(user == null)
            {
                throw new BadRequestException("Invalid username or password");
            }
            var result = _passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, dto.Password);
            if (result == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
            {
                throw new BadRequestException("Invalid username or password");
            }

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor();
            tokenDescriptor.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(_authenticationSettings.JwtExpireDays);
            tokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_authenticationSettings.JwtKey)),
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
            tokenDescriptor.Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, $"{user.role.Name}")

                });
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return tokenString;
        }
    }
}
```

Not really sure why it comes, cant fix it.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Does `user`, `user.Id`, `user.role`  is not null?

Comment: What line of code does the compiler point out? What is the full error message you are receiving?

Comment: You are right, thanks for answer. user.role was null (the rule is not included correctly)

Comment: not sure why it not includes properly with Include() function..

Comment: Changed to 
`
var user = _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Email == dto.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            user.role = _dbContext.Roles.Where(u=> u.Id == user.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
`
and it worked finally :).
Thanks for help.